# Holomorphic map between torus

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

It is well known fact that holomorphic map $f(z)$ between torus which satisfies $f(0)＝0$
is $f(z)＝az$ for some complex number $a$.

But on the other hand, I heard the fact that every holomorphic function on compact Riemann surfaces constant.Torus is clearly compact Riemann surface.

Above two facts seems contradicting, where am I missing?

Comment: that constant thing is about holomorphic functions going from a compact Riemann surface to $\mathbb C$, not to a torus

Comment: Thank you, I was relieved.

Comment: This question might have arisen while reading Forster's *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces*. When he speaks of holomorphic *functions* he means holomorphic maps to $\mathbb{C}$. When he speaks of holomorphic *mappings* he refers to holomorphic maps to any Riemann surface. Thus, in his terminology, holomorphic functions are, in particular, holomorphic mappings, but not the other way around.